# How to retrieve SSO CA Siteminder's headers from Spring + React application

Tags: reactjs, spring, request, single-sign-on, siteminder

I need to retrieve SSO Siteminder's headers from the request.
It seems it is not possible to do it from browser/js because they are server side headers.
I can see the cookie session broeser correctly set, now I need to read the headers from the request, but I could not achieve this.

I've seen some topic in which they got them using a while loop in a JSP page.

Should I do it from Java Spring or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Every server-side webapp language and framework has methods for inspecting the inbound HTTP request to see the headers, including JEE, Spring Framework, even NodeJS.